# Difference in Mercedes and Aston Martin teams in F1

Tags: formula-1

Before the start of the F1 2021 season, it was said that low rake F1 cars would be at a disadvantage because of new aerodynamic regulations by FIA. Red Bull with a high rake F1 car was slated to win all the races and they did win the first few races, if not comfortably.

Mercedes with a low rake design subsequently started competing in latter half of the season with a better straight line speed in few tracks. The same did not happen with Aston Martin that is also running on a Mercedes ICE.

With both the teams being so similar, what exactly happened to Mercedes that could not happen to Aston Martin. Mercedes does have a stake in Aston Martin but how come the former is so much superior with the same engine?

Comment: Do you work for Red Bull?

Comment: No. I am a fan of Sebastian Vettel and which ever team he goes to, I become their fan. So I used to be a fan of Red Bull when Sebastian Vettel used to drive for them.

Comment: Sorry, that was a joke.  I'm sure Red Bull would like to know as well.  I don't know that Mercedes is going to want anyone outside their team to know the real reason.  You could guess that it might be aero improvements, but it's going to be hard to get public information about it (at least for a few years).